# Batch program writing output of 'dir' in text file

Tags: batch-file, dir

I am learning about batch programming and I have got problem.

I want make a program which places the output of the `dir` command to `file.txt`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
ECHO OFF DIR > file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you are writing "OFF DIR" into to textfile:

```
ECHO OFF DIR > FILE.TXT
```

You need to place these commands on two separate lines:

```
@ECHO OFF
DIR > FILE.TXT
```

The @ sign before ECHO OFF will hide that command from showing.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose "the problem" is in `ECHO OFF`

try this

```
DIR > file.txt
```